# how to use json on httprequest setBody

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

here is my apex class I am getting this error

DEBUG|{"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted [5132df156cbaf320d27f8e06f3b61656]: logged with error code"}

````
public class makeCallOutIC1 {
    public String getContent(String url){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://api.intercom.io/contacts/search/');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + 'dGljA=';
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);  
        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Intercom-Version', '2.6');
        String body = '{'+
                       '"query": {' +
              '            "field": "last_seen_at", ' +
              '            "operator": ">", ' +
              '              "value": "1646149510",   ' +
              '        }' +
            '      }';
        
        req.setBody(body);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        return res.getBody();
        
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it fails on comma after 1646149510.

What you can do is take known good message from that API's documentation and throw it it into https://json2apex.herokuapp.com. It should generate an apex class for you that will be easier to work with. You'll be just setting fields on a object and calling Json.serialize() when you are ready. Not worrying about hand-crafting the message, escaping special characters...

It will try to guess the field types for you and you may have to tweak the generated code a bit like string -> long but still - in the long run it's more natural to work with objects than with raw JSON.

Without that parser... Well, you could take a stab at making such helper class yourself or use orgy of Map<String, Object> but it'd be cumbersome.